# fragment_main layout resource not getting created in runtime. getting NullPointerException even in onViewCreated() method

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I'm a beginner level developer learning to develop Android apps using Kotlin and I've run into some problem which I'm not able to come out of it on my own.

Here's the problem:

[image]

In the above image, there plenty of other UI objects in the layout just like **startBtn** which is a **FloatingActionButton** without a `?` beside its type declaration. Those objects are working fine in runtime and I've no problem dealing with those objects.

But, The once with `?` such as **suryaKriyaCard** which is of type **MaterialCardView?**. these view objects are not getting bound and they raise **NullPointerException**

I've seen a few threads here on stackoverflow which says that I'm trying to access those objects a bit earlier than I should and I need to move that code to `onViewCreated()` method since it'll be called by the system once all the view objects are inflated on the fragment.

Here's the code implementation:

```
  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    mainFragmentBinding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    return mainFragmentBinding.root
}


  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    if (mContext == null) {
        mContext = mainFragmentBinding.root.context
    }
    activity = requireActivity()

    manager = ReviewManagerFactory.create(mContext)
    getReviewInfo()

    utils = Utilities()

    builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)

    mainFragmentBinding.startBtn.setOnClickListener(this)
```

I'm always getting a **NullPointerException** at :

```
suryaKriyaUIcard = mainFragmentBinding.suryaKriyaCard!!
    suryaKriyaAd = mainFragmentBinding.suryaKriyaCardBelowAd!!
    shambhaviResumeBtn = mainFragmentBinding.shambhaviResumeBtn!!
```

Here's the layout xml code specific to crash:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:filterTouchesWhenObscured="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/invocation_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/invocation_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/invocation_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/invocation_card_header"
                        android:text="@string/invocation_card_header"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/play_in_progress_indicator"
                        style="@style/progress_bar_indicator_styles"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


                    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/start_btn"
                        style="@style/floating_play_buttons"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/play_invocation"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/invocation_banner" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/play_duration"
                        style="@style/kriya_sequence_time_stamps_and_rep_styles"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/invocation_banner" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/invocation_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/invocation_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
ads:adUnitId="@string/crash_course_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/crash_course_card" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/prep_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/crash_course_card_below_ad">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/prep_card_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/prep_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/prep_aasans_card_header"
                        android:text="@string/prep_aasans_card_header"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/prep_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/prep_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/prep_card" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/surya_kriya_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/prep_card_below_ad">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/surya_kriya_card_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/surya_kriya_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/surya_kriya_card_header"
                        android:text="@string/surya_kriya_card_header"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/shambhavi_resume_btn"
                        style="@style/floating_play_buttons"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/resume_shambhavi_practice"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/surya_kriya_banner" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/surya_kriya_done"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="12dp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/surya_kriya_banner" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/surya_kriya_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/surya_kriya_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/surya_kriya_card" />



            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/sukha_kriya_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/surya_kriya_card_below_ad">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sukha_kriya_card_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/sukha_kriya_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/sukha_kriya_card_header"
                        android:text="@string/sukha_kriya_card_header"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/sukha_kriya_done"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="12dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/sukha_kriya_duration"
                        style="@style/kriya_sequence_time_stamps_and_rep_styles"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/sukha_kriya_banner" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/sukha_kriya_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/sukha_kriya_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sukha_kriya_card" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/aum_chant_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/sukha_kriya_card_below_ad">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/aum_chant_card_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aum_chant_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/aum_chanting_card_header"
                        android:text="@string/aum_chanting_card_header"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/aum_chant_done"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="12dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/aum_chant_reps"
                        style="@style/kriya_sequence_time_stamps_and_rep_styles"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/aum_chant_banner" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/aum_chant_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/aum_chant_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/aum_chant_card" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/flutter_breath_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/aum_chant_card_below_ad">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/flutter_breath_card_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/flutter_breath_card_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/flutter_breath_card_header"
                        android:text="@string/flutter_breath_card_header"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/flutter_breath_done"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="12dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/flutter_breath_duration"
                        style="@style/kriya_sequence_time_stamps_and_rep_styles"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/flutter_breath_card_banner" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/flutter_breath_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/flutter_breath_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flutter_breath_card" />

            <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                android:id="@+id/meditation_card"
                style="@style/kriya_card_dimensions"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flutter_breath_card_below_ad">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/meditation_card_child"
                    style="@style/kriya_card_styles">

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/meditation_card_banner"
                        style="@style/kriya_card_header_styles"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/meditation"
                        android:text="@string/meditation"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:id="@+id/meditation_done"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="12dp"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                        android:id="@+id/meditation_duration"
                        style="@style/kriya_sequence_time_stamps_and_rep_styles"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/meditation_card_banner" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/meditation_card_below_ad"
                style="@style/banner_ad_styles"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/meditation_card_below_ad_unit_id"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/meditation_card" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</layout>
```

can anyone please help me in handling this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest that you edit your question and post your `fragment_main` layout resource.

Comment: made those changes to the question. thank you for your suggestion @CommonsWare.

Comment: Sorry, I meant posting the XML content of your `fragment_main` layout resource. Presumably, there is something in there that is causing view binding to generate those properties as being nullable. If we can see the XML, we might be able to point out the cause.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I've tried posting the layout file initially when I was posting the question but it was exceeding the charecter limit and it wasn't letting me post the question. So I had to remove it. are there any other alternatives you can suggest to post the XML? Thank you

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I have added specific layout XML code where the app is crashing. Hope this info helps. Thank you

Comment: That is not a complete layout.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, Finally I've some how I managed to fit the whole XML in it. Please have a look. I hope this info helps you in helping resolve the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Your screenshot shows `startBtn` and `crashCourseStartBtn` as being available and non-nullable. However, those do not appear in this layout file at all. That suggests that this layout file is not `fragment_main`. What is this layout file, and what is its relationship to `fragment_main`?

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, those IDs are there in the XML code, please have a look at the first FloatingActionButton. which is "startBtn" and subsequently you can find the "crashCourseStartBtn" which is also a FloatingActionButton.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot about `_` conversion. I was searching literally for `startBtn`. Unfortunately, I am not able to see what might be causing the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Not a problem. Thank you for looking into the issue. If there's anyone around you who you think can probably help with issue, can you please tag them here so that they might probably find the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you have different versions of this layout, some of which have views with these IDs, and some that do not. This causes view binding to generate a nullable property for that ID, since the view might not be present in whichever configuration of the layout is currently inflated.

When you assert non-nullable with `!!`, this will cause the NullPointerException if your current layout is one without these views. Hint: never use `!!` except in unit tests and quick experimental scripts if you don't like crashes. Variables generally are not defined as nullable for no reason.

If you didn't mean to generate multiple versions of your layout, search through your `res` directory for alternate layout files with the same name. You need to make sure you only have the default one in the `layout` directory, or else make sure every alternative version of your layout has all the views that you require in every version of your screen configuration.

For example, maybe you have two layout files in these directories:

```
res/layout/fragment_main.xml
res/layout-land/fragment_main.xml
```

and you only put those views in the landscape version of the layout file. If your device is in portrait mode, and you assert the views as non-nullable, it will throw the NPE because they don't exist.

Comment: Yeah you're right. There's v21 layout which wasn't updated with these views. Now those views turned Non-nullable and I can simply use them without any null checks. Thank you very much.